# pagescroller javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagescroller

I'm using PageScroller plugin to scroll to different sections/pages on my website. 
Basically I want the scrolling button to return back to the top of the site once it's reached the last page.

I'm trying something like this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$('#controls .next').bind('click', function(e){
        if(pageScroller.current ='3'){
            pageScroller.goTo(1);
        }
        else {
        pageScroller.next();
        }
    });
```

I'm following API's from here http://pagescroller.com/documentation/

Many thanks

Comment: add another '=' (pageScroller.current =='3')

Answer (score 0):

On your if statement you seem to be setting the pageScroller.current to 3, try evaluating instead:

```
if(pageScroller.current == '3'){
```

Comment: Cheers, works a treat. Although, the smooth scrolling doesn't seem to work when it goes back to top. It's very abrupt, but it works fine scrolling down.

Comment: Probably because it is using the same time to scroll one page down that it is using to scroll 2 pages up (this should be slower), so you might have to update the 'goTo' method and maybe add some extra time to the scroll animation.